# Variable not detected as being declared

Tags: vb.net, variable-declaration

Alright, I'm playing around with visual basic and seem to be having a hell of a time getting started on it xD. Anyways not sure why I am getting the following error:

> `UACLevel_Level` is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I tried clicking the little help icon thing and it gave me nothing.

```
Dim ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin", Nothing)
Dim EnableLUA = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "EnableLUA", Nothing)
Dim PromptOnSecureDesktop = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "PromptOnSecureDesktop", Nothing)
Dim UACLevel_Value = ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin + EnableLUA + PromptOnSecureDesktop
If UACLevel_Value = 0 Then
    Dim UACLevel_Level = "Never notify me."
ElseIf UACLevel_Value = 6 Then
    Dim UACLevel_Level = "Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer(do not dim desktop)."
ElseIf UACLevel_Value = 7 Then
    Dim UACLevel_Level = "Default - Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer."
ElseIf UACLevel_Value = 4 Then
    Dim UACLevel_Level = "Always Notify Me"
Else
    Dim UACLevel_Level = "Customized UAC Level"
End If
MsgBox("UACLevel is " & UACLevel_Value & ": " & UACLevel_Level)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested the final result was as follows.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin", Nothing)
        Dim EnableLUA = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "EnableLUA", Nothing)
        Dim PromptOnSecureDesktop = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System", "PromptOnSecureDesktop", Nothing)
        Dim UACLevel_Value = ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin + EnableLUA + PromptOnSecureDesktop
        Dim UACLevel_level As String
        If UACLevel_Value = 0 Then
            UACLevel_level = "Never notify me."
        ElseIf UACLevel_Value = 6 Then
            UACLevel_level = "Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer(do not dim desktop)."
        ElseIf UACLevel_Value = 7 Then
            UACLevel_level = "Default - Notify me only when programs try to make changes to my computer."
        ElseIf UACLevel_Value = 4 Then
            UACLevel_level = "Always Notify Me"
        Else
            UACLevel_level = "Customized UAC Level"
        End If
        MsgBox("UACLevel is " & UACLevel_Value & ": " & UACLevel_Level)

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 5):

`UACLevel_Level` is declared inside an `If` block. Variable declared inside a code block is only visible from that block.

This is different to VB6/VBA, where it would be visible outside the block (at which point you would get a multiple declaration error, because you declare it five times).

Declare `UACLevel_Level` outside the `If` block, and only assign a value to it in the `If` block.

See [Scope in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t0wsc67.aspx) for future reference.

Comment: Thank you, it took a bit of playing around with but I got it working thank you!

Comment: @user1451070 You mean hide the console window which is your application? You could create a shortcut to your program and set in the shortcut that it should be launched hidden, but if your goal is to display a message box, you should have not created a console app in the first place. Create a new windows forms project, create a module, paste that code there, go to the project properties, application tab, uncheck "Enable application framework," select "Sub Main" for the "Startup object", close and save settings, delete the Form1 form, compile.